# RancherOS - automatically join cluster

Tags: rancher

I'm planning to boot from **baremetal servers using iPXE**.
I will be loading RancherOS on them.

I want to make it such that **when the RancherOS boots - it automatically joins the cluster**.

I believe this must be done through a **cloud config**, does anyone have an example that will make the nodes automatically join a cluster of my choice?

I know that the cloud config is loaded by a URL which means it is exposed and contains the registration token and that would allow any node to join the cluster. If there are better way - let me know.